# Android destroys global HashMap

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I want to add a HashMap to a singelton (which will be the application instance object) to pass data between activites. I cant use a Bundle as the objects are too big to be passed through an intent.

I'm currently using this implementation:

```
public class MyApp extends Application { 

    private static MyApp singelton;
    private static Map<String, Object> tempDataStorage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singelton = this;
        tempDataStorage = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    // puts the object in the Map and returns the key
    public static String putDataInStorage(Object data) {
        String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString() // generate a key
        tempDataStorage.put(key, data);
    }

    // gets the object from the Map and deletes it to save memory
    public static Object getDataFromStorage(String key) {
        Object o = tempDataStorage.get(key);
        tempDataStorage.remove(key);
    }
}
```

putDataInStorage() is called from activity A to pass the data to activity B which then calls getDataFromStorage() with the key passed through the intent. If activity B gets destroyed by android, it also calles putDataInStorage() in its onSaveInstanceState() method to reclaim the data later.

Im still having a problem with android destroying my application after some time if the app is not used. If the user then comes back, it seems to recreate Activity B with the Bundle from saveInstanceState, while the new HashMap is empty.

I first thought about writing the Data from the Map into an SQL-Database when the app is destroyed and recreate the objects on recreation. But this would lead into an endlessly growing Map (and therfore endlessly growing memory usage) as the objects would never disappear. Not a good solution though.

As the data is fetched from a webserver, my second idea was to also save a reference to the data in the saveInstanceState() of Activity B (eg. the parameters of the GET-request). If activity B is then confronted with a NullPointerException, it can refetch the data.

Is that a good solution? If not, whats a better one?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You should not count on saving dynamic data. Application can be killed at any time when other apps need memory. Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save your data permanently.

Comment: I dont want to save the data permanently. I just want to be sure that its there when the activity is recreated because android destroys it when its in background. And its sometimes too big to save it directly via saveInstanceState as android only alows 1MB of data

Comment: Yeah, anyway app memory can be destroyed, you can save your data in OnDestroy method and add null checking for tempDataStorage in onCreate. If null then restore your map from sharedpreferences. Hope it will help

Comment: THat was exactly what i first thought about, but with an sql-db instead of sharedprefs as the objects are big and nested. The problem is if i would save the map everytime its destroyed and reload it, the map would grow endlessly over the days of usage.. So the second approach seems to be a better one as the data is available on the server anyway.

Comment: JFI, android doesn't gurantee call to onDestroy() when closing application for reclaiming memory. Saving criticial info should be done in onPause().